# Link to a specific slide from Flash file embeded in PowerPoint

Tags: vb.net, flash, actionscript, macros, powerpoint

I am creating an interactive map in Flash that will be embedded in PowerPoint. I would like to have some hot spots on the Flash map that will link to specific PowerPoint slides within the presentation. Does anyone know how this would be coded?

I found a video that uses VB inside PowerPoint to link to the next slide, but it does not show how to pick a single slide: http://youtu.be/9YLqd8dKhcg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided:

```
Private Sub ShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(ByVa­l command As String, ByVal args As String)
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.Next
End With
End Sub
```

Change that to:

```
Private Sub ShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(ByVa­l command As String, ByVal args As String)
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
  .GoToSlide(lSlideIndex)
End With
End Sub
```

`lSlideIndex` is a long = the ordinal number of the slide in the presentation.  i.e., if you want to go to 42nd slide, `.GoToSlide(42)`