# Link to a slide from Flash file embeded in PowerPoint

Tags: flash, vbscript

I'm creating an animated menu in Flash that I want to embed in PowerPoint and be able to jump to slides in the PowerPoint when clicking buttons in the Flash.

In the Flash the code for communicating with the PowerPoint is:

```
fig1.onRelease=function(){
fscommand("",2)
}
```

where fig1 is the movie clip button and fscommand passes the parameters to VBscript attached to the embedded SWF in PowerPoint. The '2' is the slide number I want it to jump to.

In the PowerPoint I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub ShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(ByVa­l command, ByVal args)
With ShockwaveFlash1.SlideShowWindows(1).View
  .GotoSlide (args)
End With
End Sub
```

This code is based on code from another post on this website that was an answer to someone with a similar problem.

[Link to a specific slide from Flash file embeded in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519794/link-to-a-specific-slide-from-flash-file-embeded-in-powerpoint?answertab=votes#tab-top)

My problem is that it's not working for me and I'm getting this VB error:

```
Compile error: 
Expected list separator or )
```

Along with this error, the word 'command' is highlighted in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you just copy/pasted a VBA macro to a VBScript file. That won't work, since there are [notable differences](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) between the two languages. This particular error is most likely caused by the type definitions in the procedure signature. Change this:

```
Private Sub ShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(ByVa­l command As String, ByVal args As String)
```

into this:

```
Private Sub ShockwaveFlash1_FSCommand(ByVa­l command, ByVal args)
```

You may also need to change

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View
```

into

```
ppt.SlideShowWindows(1).View
```

or

```
ppt.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindows(1).View
```

where `ppt` is a variable referencing your PowerPoint application object.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did as you suggested but am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Then please update your question with the entire VBScript code you're using now and the exact error message, including the number of the line raising the error.

Comment: I updated my original question as you requested.  Note - the error message gives no line number but the command variable is highlighted in the first line of the code.

Comment: Hmm... when I copy/paste the VBScript code from your question to a text editor I get a spurious character between `a` and `l` of the first `ByVal`. Try deleting and re-typing that keyword (or remove the `ByVal command,` entirely, since you're not using that parameter anyway).

Comment: I corrected the typo and reran the script and now get a new error: 

Compile error:

Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name.

Comment: If you removed the first argument, you also need to change `fscommand("",2)` to `fscommand(2)` in the ActionScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Ansgar.  It turns out part of the problem was that I had the wrong name for the Flash object.  Right-clicking the SWF and selecting Properties from the contextual menu shows the SWF object name. I made a couple of VB code tweaks and kept the Actionscript the same.

Final Actionscript (button code in Flash):

```
fig1.onRelease=function(){
fscommand("", 2)
}
```

Final VB code:

```
Private Sub ArticulateFlashObject_FSCommand(ByVal command As String, ByVal args As String)
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
.GotoSlide args
End With
End Sub
```